# How to check whether a linked list is circular or not?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an efficient algorithm to find whether a singly linked list is circular/cyclic or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103522/what-is-an-efficient-algorithm-to-find-whether-a-singly-linked-list-is-circular-c)

How to check if a Linked list is circular or not efficiently? It will be more helpful if your answers are based on C/C++ perspective. Thanks.